# How can I paginate Pagerduty REST API results when requesting incident lists?

Tags: pagination, pagerduty

I'm building an application which pulls down incident listings for my org via Pagerduty's REST API.

The `GET /incidents` endpoint [does respond](https://api-reference.pagerduty.com/#!/Incidents/get_incidents) with `more`, `offset`, and other keys that are [indicative of pagination being supported](https://v2.developer.pagerduty.com/v2/docs/pagination), and it does make intuitive sense on this endpoint, but I haven't been able to actually paginate these results:

- Passing `offset` or `limit` as a query param returns a 403
- Passing these in various forms in request headers just gets ignored entirely

Is there a way to paginate these results at all?

Answer (score 0):

it might help to include the code you're using to make the request, or a curl request from the command line. Including pagination parameters shouldn't lead to a 403, so I'm thinking something else might be missing.

You should be able to paginate the lists using GET parameters, e.g

```
https://api.pagerduty.com/incidents?limit=20&offset=100
```

`limit` has a maximum value of `100`, and `limit + offset` together must be less than `10,000`. That might be why you were getting an error?

See [here](https://v2.developer.pagerduty.com/docs/pagination) for additional details on the pagination parameters

Comment: I was using `limit` and `offset` with much smaller values, but at this point I'm not using the Pagerduty API for this task -- it was too much trouble to stand a script up with these issues.

Comment: I'm suspecting you were running into some other kind of issue if you were getting a 403.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to paginate the results.

After invoking the API method for the first time, you need to check the `more` response field value. If true, then you can call the API method again with an updated `offset`.

`offset` is related to the total results, and **not** the total pages.

The 403 error code response you're getting is most likely related to the user permissions and not with paginating results.